# Firebase AuthUI iOS customisation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am attempting to customise the colour scheme of the default Firebase AuthUI screens on iOS. I can change the NavigationBar text colour however I cannot not change the left LeftNavigationBarItem text properties or the main view background colour.

This is the code that I've used to change the main text properties on the NavigationBar:

```
let authVC = authUI!.authViewController()
authVC.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
authVC.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
authVC.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor (displayP3Red: 255/255, green: 212/255, blue: 121/255, alpha: 1.0)]
```

I have tried the following code, a line at a time, to change the NavigationBarItem text properties:

```
authVC.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor (displayP3Red: 255/255, green: 212/255, blue:121/255, alpha: 1.0) ], for: .normal)
authVC.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor (displayP3Red: 255/255, green: 212/255, blue: 121/255, alpha: 1.0) ], for: .normal)
```

I have tried this to change the view background properties, again a line at a time:

```
authVC.visibleViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black 
authVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black  
authVC.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
authVC.visibleViewController?.view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

I'm using FirebaseUI (5.2.0), FirebaseAuth (5.0.3) & Xcode 9.4.1.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

code below is how you would change the background color as scoobydoo pointed out, also I was able to modify my authViewController after I added the custom controller as the root like so

let authViewController = MyAuthPickerViewController(authUI: authUI)

nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: authViewController)

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseUI

class MyAuthPickerViewController : FUIAuthPickerViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scrollView = view.subviews[0]
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear
        let contentView = scrollView.subviews[0]
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear

        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -1, width: width, height: height))

        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "switchStarback")
        backgroundImage.alpha = 0.6
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(named: "MatteBlack")

        backgroundImage.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill

        view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been sorted by subclassing FUIAuthPickerViewController and setting the view.backgroundColor in viewDidLoad method

Comment: Do you have the subclass code handy? Trying to get this to work.